# Foundation Modal semi-transparent background cuts off

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

Okay so here is the demo site:
http://hayati.yahyauddin.com/

To see the modal, hover over a product and click the zoom button to display the quick view for the product.

If you continue scrolling down, you will see that the Gray semi-transparent background stops. This problem occurs regardless of screen size!

[image: Problem 1]

Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Note: This problem does not seem to occur in the foundation website:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zurb guys changed its default position from fixed to absolute (i didn't understand why) then they changed their mind and went back to fixed again.

This was implemented in 5.5.1
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/commit/45f9b407ffeeca4b44c5a2afde4f0e58abf4bb78

updating will help :)

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have sort of fixed the issue. the problem was that in the _reveal.scss, position was set as absolute oddly enough. There is a comment that says `allows modal background to extend beyond window position` for the mix in. This was clearly NOT the case.

I just changed the `position: absolute` to `position: fixed` and it works!

Feel free to leave a comment as to why you think the devs did this.